# Proper Use of Transactions

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, transaction

I am learning more about SQL as I work on this Database project.  Today I encountered Transactions, and after looking at what they are and how they work, my first thought was, "Shit, I need to change my Procedures to use these."

Throughout today I have been looking on here, and Google is trying to find out when it is appropriate to use a Transaction, on how to correctly write the syntax for one.  I honestly haven't found much, so I'm essentially writing this so that I can see if I am implementing these properly, and for anyone who may be looking for something like this in the future (hello Google).

So I've mostly been throwing Transactions into any Procedure I have created which either inserts data or deletes data.  It seems to me that if I am querying data, not manipulating it, transactions aren't necessary.  If I am wrong in this thinking, please feel free to illuminate me.

So this is an example of me using a Transaction in a Procedure that is Deleting Data:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteOrder
    @OrderNum VARCHAR(20)
) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @OrderID INT

    IF(EXISTS(SELECT order_id FROM purchase_orders WHERE order_number = @OrderNum))
    BEGIN
        SELECT @OrderID = order_id
          FROM purchase_orders
         WHERE order_number = @OrderNum
    END
    ELSE
        RETURN 1

    BEGIN TRANSACTION DelOrder
        BEGIN TRY
            DELETE FROM order_parts
             WHERE order_id = @OrderID
            DELETE FROM purchase_price_logs
             WHERE order_id = @OrderID
            DELETE FROM purchase_orders
             WHERE order_id = @OrderID
            COMMIT TRANSACTION DelOrder
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION DelOrder
            RETURN 1
        END CATCH
END
```

The first question I have is; Is my syntax correct?  Am I implementing the Transaction appropriately?  Is there a way you would code what I am trying to do differently?  For that last question, it's more about the whole Procedure than just the Transaction segment.

Finally, I have a question I thought of while writing this post.  Is it possible to have said a 'Master Rollback' or 'Master Commit' procedure, where while you have a connection going on with the database, no transactions are committed until your 'Master Commit' Procedure is called?  Something like.

```
MasterCommit
    For Each Transaction
        Commit Transaction
```

With something similar being the same for Rolling back.  I know of the existence of SavePoints, so is this where they'd be helpful?  More so with the Rollbacks than the Commits I suppose.

Comment: These are a lot of very different questions. Transaction looks fine, you might want to raise an error inside `CATCH` so the consumer knows it failed (and why, since there are multiple possible reasons), unless you are trying to make it fail gracefully.

Comment: As for `IF EXISTS (SELECT) SELECT @var = val from same SELECT` just do `SELECT @var = ; IF @var IS NULL RETURN;` - there is no reason to query the table once just to query it a second time.

Comment: And as for your master commit idea, there is not really any concept of multiple concurrent transactions by the same session. Yes, you can increase trancount > 1, but one commit commits them all, so the master doesn't really serve any purpose.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Most of these Procedures are going to be called from a VB.Net program.  I don't know how I'd pass the error back.  Would simply doing `PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()` or something work?

Comment: Sorry, I have never used VB.Net, but I know in C# you have access to the exceptions raised by `THROW()` or `RAISERROR()`. I don't know what you can do with `PRINT` output.

Comment: VB.Net works similarly.

Comment: I suggest you add `SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of procs with explict transactions, That way, the transaction will be rolled back immediately in the event of a command timeout.